# JPAのエンティティにSerializableインタフェースを実装すべき状況は？

Tags: java, jpa

JPAのエンティティにSerializableインタフェースを実装しなければならないのは、どのような状況でしょうか？
いくつか英語の情報は得られたのですが、英語が苦手なこともあり、理解できませんでした：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020904/when-and-why-jpa-entities-should-implement-serializable-interface
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/do_jpa_entities_have_to
https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Java-Entity-need-to-implement-Serializable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それらのリンクの記事の中では2つのケースが挙げられています。

ひとつはエンティティオブジェクトが複数のJVM間でやりとりされる場合。例えば、EJBのリモートインターフェースに渡す場合などです。

もうひとつは`HTTPSession`にエンティティオブジェクトを保存する場合。`HTTPSession`インスタンスは、冗長化、キャッシュ、最適化などのために、シリアライズされてストレージに格納されることがあるようで、その際に`Serializable`を実装していないエンティティオブジェクトを保存しているとエラーになるそうです。